# mariadb hanging on insert for several seconds

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

My test environment is in Openstack vm. There is a python demo program, insert into mariadb table per second and show the consuming time of insert. When I do a large disk operation，such as copy a big directory，or dd a file of 1G，the consuming time of insert will be longer obviously. Most to be 10 second. But at the same time，there are another test shell, echo a long string to file per 0.1 second, and tail -f it, there is no hanging. It runs very fast.
What I am confused is，What is the different between file writing and mysql insert data into table?
Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I use innodb storage engine

Comment: One might not actually flush data to disk and keep it in memory buffers

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen,Hi,you means the echo not wirte bytes to disk actually?How can I make sure?

Comment: Among other factors, `SELECT @@INNODB_FLUSH_LOG_AT_TRX_COMMIT;`.  If the the value is 1, not 2 (or 0), then InnoDB is not merely writing to disk, but ensuring that the disk write is actually committed to the disk, with fsync.  Writing to a file with echo makes no similar effort.

Comment: This is the problem of echo, not directly written to disk. After fsync.the phenomenon is the same to mysql! By the way,Is there a difference between 'writing to disk' and 'committed to disk'?@Michael

Comment: How are you timing the slow `INSERT`?  Let's see the `INSERT`.  Let's see the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Is a huge `TEXT` or `BLOB` involved; in other words, how big is the row(s)?

Comment: How do you see the "hang"?